# Calculate $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{x-\sin(x)}{x^3(1+x^2)}$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, residue-calculus

Calculate $$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{x-\sin(x)}{x^3(1+x^2)}$$

I know i am supposed to use residue theorem. However, I am having trouble with the pole at $z=0$ normally i would try the funciton $$f(z)=\frac{z-e^{iz}}{z^3(1+z^2)}$$ but this clearly is not working  as this function has a pole of order 3 at $z=0$. if i try to reduce the order of the pole i would need to do something along those lines:
$$f(z)=\frac{z-ie^{iz}+i}{z^3(1+z^2)}$$ and here the pole is simple, but integrating this function will not give me the desired integral, I don' think. What do I do?

Edit:

Perhaps $y=x^2$ substitution and keyhole integration would work. I will have to check.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
&\bbox[10px,#ffd]{\int_{0}^{\infty}{x - \sin\pars{x} \over
x^{3}\pars{1 + x^{2}}}\,\dd x}=
{1 \over 2}\,\Im\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\ic x - \expo{\ic x} + 1 - x^{2}/2 \over
x^{3}\pars{1 + x^{2}}}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] = &\
{1 \over 2}\,\Im\braces{2\pi\ic\,%
{\ic\pars{\ic} - \expo{\ic\pars{\ic}} + 1 - \ic^{2}/2 \over 
\ic^{3}\pars{\ic + \ic}}} = \bbx{\large{\expo{} -2 \over 4\expo{}}\,\pi} \\ &
\end{align}

---

The $\ds{\large\left. contribution\ from\ the\ arc\  R\expo{\ic\pars{0,\pi}}\,\right\vert_{\ R\ >\ 1}}$:

\begin{align}
0 & < \verts{\int_{0}^{\pi}
{\ic R\expo{\ic\theta} -
\expo{\ic R\cos\pars{\theta}}\expo{-R\sin\pars{\theta}} + 1 -
R^{2}\expo{2\ic\theta} \over
R^{3}\expo{3\ic\theta}\pars{1 + R^{2}\expo{2\ic\theta}}}\,R\expo{\ic\theta}\ic\,\dd\theta}
\\[5mm] & <
\int_{0}^{\pi}{R + \expo{-R\sin\pars{\theta}} + 1 + R^{2} \over
R^{3}\pars{R^{2} - 1}}\,R\,\dd\theta
\\[5mm] & =
{R^{2} + R + 1 \over R^{2}\pars{R^{2} - 1}}\,\pi +
{1 \over R^{2}\pars{R^{2} - 1}}
\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\expo{-R\cos\pars{\theta}}\dd\theta
\\[5mm] & \stackrel{\mrm{as}\ R\ \to\ \infty}{\sim}\,\,\,
{2 \over R^{4}}
\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\expo{-R\sin\pars{\theta}}\dd\theta <
{2 \over R^{4}}
\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\expo{-2R\theta/\pi}\dd\theta
\\[5mm] & =
\pi\,{1 - \expo{-R} \over R^{5}}
\,\,\,\stackrel{\mrm{as}\ R\ \to\ \infty}{\LARGE\to}\,\,\,
{\large\color{red}{0}}
\end{align}

Comment: Ugh, I thought i learned you trick by trying the $+i$ but i guess it can be taken even further :P. Thank you again for illuminating me.

Comment: @2132123 The main purpose is to avoid the divergence of the integral under $\displaystyle\Im$ without modifyng, of course, its value. Thanks.

Comment: Can some one explain or just name the theory/method behind this amazing solution. A good ref./siurce will hrlp me more. Please respond to help me I have never seen such a simple solution of a complicated integral.

Comment: @DharmendraSingh this is just residue thoerem. Felix sorry to bother you again, but how do you justify the convergence of the integral?

Comment: @2132123 I add something about that. Please, check the answer very end.

Comment: @FelixMarin Oh I am sorry, I think I was not clear as to what integral I was referring to. I meant the original integral. The residue theorem give the Cauchy principal value and there has to be justification, aka the integral exists, to say CPV is equal to the value of the integral.

Comment: @2132123 Thanks for the explanation, otherwise I thought that it was a sheer magic.

Answer (score 1):

Define
$$ I(a)=\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{ax-\sin(ax)}{x^3(1+x^2)}dx. $$
Then
\begin{eqnarray}
I'(a)&=&\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1-\cos(ax)}{x^2(1+x^2)}dx\\
I''(a)&=& \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(ax)}{x(1+x^2)}dx\\
I'''(a)&=&\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\cos(ax)}{1+x^2}dx=\frac\pi2 e^{-a}
\end{eqnarray}
and hence
\begin{eqnarray}
I''(a)&=&\int_0^a\frac\pi2 e^{-s}ds=\frac\pi2(1-e^{-a})\\
I'(a)&=&\int_0^a\frac\pi2(1-e^{-s})ds=\frac\pi2(a-1+e^{-a})\\
I(1)&=&\int_0^1\frac\pi2(a-1+e^{-a})da=\frac{(e-2)\pi}{4e}.
\end{eqnarray}

Answer (score 0):

Here is an elementary evaluation

\begin{align}
&\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{x-\sin x}{x^3(1+x^2)}dx\\
=& \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{x-\sin x}{x^3}dx
 - \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{1+x^2}dx
+\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sin x}{x(1+x^2)}dx\\
=&\ \frac\pi4-\frac\pi2+\frac{(e-1)\pi}{2e}=\frac{(e-2)\pi}{4e}
\end{align}